# control horizontal spacing between geom_bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(12351234)
names <- factor(rep(paste("C", 1:10, sep = "_"), each = 10))
time <- rep(1:10, 10)
outcome <- rnorm(mean = 1e7, sd = 1e7, n = length(time))
outcome <-ifelse(outcome < 0, 0, outcome)
data.toy <- data.frame(names, time, outcome)
ggplot(data = data.toy, aes(y = outcome, x = time)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = names)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(data.toy$time))
```

and it produces the following image: http://picpaste.com/data_toy-OR0jVHj5.png

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the horizontal "gray" space between the bars on the x-axis (the space that the arrows are pointing at). I suspect I am using this geom incorrectly as time is not categorical and there is a more appropriate geom for this.

Comment: Use `width = 1` inside your `geom_bar`

Comment: Thanks. that solved my problem. I can't tell you how many hours I spent googling this and you solved it in 5 minutes. Thanks.